# Why won't the "Account not found" line not work? Still a beginner at coding and have tried if and else statements

Tags: python

Basic Bank App

```
print('------------------------------------------------')
print("Welcome to Anthony's Bank App! ")
print('------------------------------------------------')
Names=[]
Accounts=[]
Balance=[]
def popArray():
    print("---------------------------------------------")
    for aNumber in range (5):
        AccountName = input("Enter a name for the account (or enter E to go to menu):" )
        if AccountName == "E" or AccountName == "e":
            choicesMenu()
        else:
            Names.append(AccountName)
        AccountID = input("Enter account ID number: ")
        Accounts.append(AccountID)
        BalanceVal = (int(input("Enter an account balance: ")))
        Balance.append(BalanceVal)
    choicesMenu()

def searchArray():
    position = 0
    accountIDstr=input("Please enter your account ID number: ")
    for aNumber in range(10):
        if (accountIDstr == Accounts[position]):
            break
        if (accountIDstr != Accounts[position]):
            position += 1
    if (accountIDstr == Accounts[position]):
        print("---------------------------------------------")
        print("Account Holder: ", Names[position])
        print("Balance: $", Balance[position])
        choicesMenu()
    else:
        print("Account not found. Please try again...")
        choicesMenu()

def depArray():
    position = 0
    accountIDstr=input("Please enter your account ID number: ")
    for aNumber in range(5):
        if (accountIDstr == Accounts[position]):
            break
        if (accountIDstr != Accounts[position]):
            position += 1
    balanceAmt = Balance[position]
    print("---------------------------------------------")
    print("Account Holder: ", Names[position])
    print("Balance: $", balanceAmt)
    depositAmt=int(input("Enter deposit amount: "))
    NewBalance = int(balanceAmt) + depositAmt
    total = NewBalance
    Balance[position]=total
    print("---------------------------------------------")
    print("New Balance: $", Balance[position])
    choicesMenu()

def wdrawArray():
    position=0
    accountIDstr=input("Please enter your account ID number: ")
    for aNumber in range(5):
        if (accountIDstr == Accounts[position]):
            break
        if (accountIDstr != Accounts[position]):
            position += 1
    balanceAmt = Balance[position]
    balanceVal = int(balanceAmt)
    print("---------------------------------------------")
    print("Account Holder: ", Names[position])
    print("Balance: $", balanceVal)
    withdrawAmt=int(input("Enter withdraw amount: "))
    if withdrawAmt > balanceVal:
        print("------------------------------------------------")
        print("Insufficient Funds. Try again...")
        choicesMenu()
    else:
        NewBalance = balanceVal - withdrawAmt
        total = NewBalance
        Balance[position]=total
        print("---------------------------------------------")
        print("New Balance: $", Balance[position])
        choicesMenu()

def exitArray():
    print("------------------------------------------------")
    print("Thank you for using Anthony's Bank App. Have a nice day! ")
    print(":)")
    quit()

def choicesMenu():
    print("------------------------------------------------")
    print("Enter P to populate accounts.")
    print("Enter S to search for an account.")
    print("Enter E to exit the app.")
    print("Enter D to deposit funds into an account.")
    print("Enter W to withdraw funds from an account.")
    inputStr = input("Please pick a choice: ")
    if inputStr == "P" or inputStr == "p":
        popArray()
    if inputStr == "S" or inputStr == "s":
        searchArray()
    if inputStr == "E" or inputStr == "e":
        exitArray()
    if inputStr == "D" or inputStr == "d":
        depArray()
    if inputStr == "W" or inputStr == "w":
        wdrawArray()
    else:
        print("Invalid choice. Try again...")
        choicesMenu()
choicesMenu()
```

### This area is the area that is wrong

After populating(creating) accounts ,searching for accounts, and entering an account ID that is not in the list of Accounts, it should display "Account not found. Please try again". However when I run it, it shows an error instead of displaying the prompt. Any suggestions or things I am doing wrong? I am currently learning python.

```
def searchArray():
    position = 0
    accountIDstr=input("Please enter your account ID number: ")
    for aNumber in range(10):
        if (accountIDstr == Accounts[position]):
            break
        if (accountIDstr != Accounts[position]):
            position += 1
    if (accountIDstr == Accounts[position]):
        print("---------------------------------------------")
        print("Account Holder: ", Names[position])
        print("Balance: $", Balance[position])
        choicesMenu()
    else:
        print("Account not found. Please try again...")
        choicesMenu()
```

Comment: Can you state what the error was? Or provide the traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 106, in <module>
    choicesMenu()
  File "main.py", line 94, in choicesMenu
    popArray()
  File "main.py", line 12, in popArray
    choicesMenu()
  File "main.py", line 96, in choicesMenu
    searchArray()
  File "main.py", line 24, in searchArray
    if (accountIDstr == Accounts[position]):
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Yep, it's exactly what I stated in my answer. Stay tuned, though. I'm going to add some stuff to it

Comment: Okay then, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided the error, I'm going to guess what the error is:

Inside your `searchArray` function, you increment `position` up to 10 times. If you don't have 10 accounts in `Accounts` and you are looking for an `accountIDstr` that isn't in `Accounts`, you will try to index outside the range of the list.

---

Short term fix is to say something like this:

```
for aNumber in range(len(Accounts)):
```

But I'd highly recommend looking into some better and more Pythonic solutions. See below for one potential place to start.

---

Longer term:

It's definitely a good start, though I would seriously consider restructuring your program. You can still format it with classes or functions, but it's not a good idea to have the functions make an infinite amount of calls to each other.

If run for long enough, you will have problems with recursing too deep with this code. For example, your `choicesMenu` function calls itself. I see what you are doing (in order to loop it), but you should really be using a [`while` loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp) here.

And here's why: When `choicesMenu` hasn't hit a `return` or implicitly returned, and makes a call to some other function, Python has to remember the state of `choicesMenu` so when it comes back from that other function, it will know where it left off. If `choicesMenu` just keeps calling itself, it will fill up that memory.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 106, in <module>
    choicesMenu()
  File "main.py", line 94, in choicesMenu
    popArray()
  File "main.py", line 12, in popArray
    choicesMenu()
  File "main.py", line 96, in choicesMenu
    searchArray()
  File "main.py", line 24, in searchArray
    if (accountIDstr == Accounts[position]):
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @ANTHONYFLORES-ALVAREZ I don't have too much more time to help out tonight, but definitely look into `while` loops and `for` loops (especially how they work in Python). Then consider looking into classes. All of these things should have some great tutorials just from googling them. =) Good luck